# How to format multiple Date type columns in dd/mm/yyyy using Google Sheets Api in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-sheets-api

I have multiple date type columns like "User Joining Date", "Birthdate", "Arrival Date" etc. These dates are already in dd/mm/yyyy format. 
But the issue is gsheet interprets date like 02/01/2019 as 1st February 2019 but interprets 13/01/2019 as 13th January 2019 which causes formatting issue.

02/01/2019 is left aligned whereas 13/01/2019 is right aligned. Moreover, this also causes sorting issues.

I've tried changing the locale and language of the spreadsheet but nothing helped.

Comment: Have you tried a less ambiguous format like yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure if you want to retrieve or store data, and if this is a programming issue or a Google Sheets configuration. Could you provide an example spreadsheet and / or show some code to illustrate your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can always deliver the date in the way Google Sheets expects, in your case `mm/dd/yyyy`.

You can transform a *Time*, *Date* or *DateTime* instances into any format you want by using [`#strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Time.html#method-i-strftime). This outputs a string in the provided format. Have a look at http://www.strftime.net/ for the different options and a live demo.

Alternatively you can use the [localize functionality](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#the-public-i18n-api) of Ruby on Rails. This can be done by calling:

```
I18n.l your_time_variable, format: :default
```

Comment: Personally I find https://foragoodstrftime.com/ the best reference - gives you lots of templates to work from